# How to set this Layout that fit to Any Screen height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I have Some layout Problem regarding my Application.
This is My Application Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/tax_calculator_logo"/>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <Button android:id="@+id/contactUs" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Contact Us"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/contactUs" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Contact Us"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>   
    <Button android:id="@+id/contactUs" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Contact Us"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>   
    <Button android:id="@+id/contactUs" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Contact Us"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Here, I want to set this all button to be complete fit with the height of the Screen of any device.
Yes i can show all the Button. but i want them all to be have equat space between them and they must be fit complete to the Screen height.
So what should i have to do for that ??

Edited:

And there is, My tax_calculator_logo is of 600x239 resolution and i have set the ImageView height as wrap_content and width with fill_parent then why the Image is croping from bottom and top ???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Give equal weight to each of your buttons, they will share height automatically.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactUs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Contact Us"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactUs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Contact Us"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactUs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Contact Us"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactUs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Contact Us"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wow. ..  Its Work great. Thanks. Will you please give me some idea about weight ? I mean how i have use it ? and What it will do ???

Comment: please See my Edited Question also. . .

Comment: Please Help me regarding the Edited Question also.

Comment: use android:scaleType="fitXY", for your imageView may be.

Answer (score 2):

To do this we have to get he display(screen) width and height.Then through java code assign the height. For exmple

The xml file is like this

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:src="@drawable/tax_calculator_logo"/>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp" android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

<Button android:id="@+id/contactUs" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Contact Us"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/contactUs" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Contact Us"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>   
<Button android:id="@+id/contactUs" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Contact Us"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>   
<Button android:id="@+id/contactUs" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Contact Us"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

In the Activity class

```
  Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
  int width = display.getWidth();
  int height = display.getHeight()/5;
```

after setContentView(..);

```
 imageview.getLayoutParams().height=height;
 button1.getLayoutParams().height=height;
 button2.getLayoutParams().height=height;
 button3.getLayoutParams().height=height;
 button4.getLayoutParams().height=height;
```

I think this may help you...