# Android Custom Keyboard not resizing the window Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, keyboard, android-keypad

Hi i am following [this link](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) for implementing `CustomKeyboard`. Everything was perfect except if there are number of `EditTexts` in my layout. The window is not resizing when the `keyboard` appears, say if i am trying to enter  data to `EditTexts` which are placed on bottom gets covered by the `keyboard`. The solutions  like adjust `resize` and adjust pan with the `manifest` are not working in this case, also i tried with putting `ScrollView` in `layout`, but not getting any solution. Please see my layout given below.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edittext0"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/txt"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edittext1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/txt"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edittext2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edittext3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
    android:inputType="text" />


 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edittext5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
    android:inputType="text" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext7"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edittext6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
    android:inputType="text" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext8"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edittext7"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
    android:inputType="text" />



<!-- NOTE No need to develop a system service for keyboard, there is a standard View for that (well, not completely standard, its in a funny package 'android.inputmethodservice'. -->
<!-- NOTE The graphical layout does not know the package ('java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView') so the keyboard is not shown. -->
<!-- <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:background="@drawable/normal"/>
 -->
<nl.fampennings.keyboard.CustomKeyboardView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" 
   android:keyBackground="@drawable/samplekeybackground"/>
```

Please help me with a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Use Linear Layout with some weights  instead of Relative Layouthttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633382/how-to-set-this-layout-that-fit-to-any-screen-height

Comment: Is that related to custom input method and window re-sizing when keyboard appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I  got the solution. Please find the modified layout code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edittext0"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/txt"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edittext1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/txt"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edittext2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edittext3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edittext5"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edittext6"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edittext7"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <nl.fampennings.keyboard.CustomKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/samplekeybackground"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add a linearLayout as the child of main parent layout; Add a scroll View to that layout  with weight 1 and add another layout to the scrollView as the container for child items like EditTexts and all. The keyboard view should be added in the same layout as the scrollView contains. I hope the solution will be helpful for someone.